# Microsoft Visual Studio Vertical Tabs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tabs, panel, c#

Is it possible to achieve this?
 [image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/36/tabcontrol.jpg/]

I want it to be buttons so that everytime I click it specific Panel Will pop up.

It's A WinForm. Please help me! I've been searching the net for 4 hours and I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can:

- create a panel and dock it to left and put every button you need inside it
- create a panel for every button and set it invisible

When user press a button show the correct panel and set its dock property to fill.

Comment: @warook: remember to accept a solution if you find it's the right one for you. This way you "close" your question telling SO mates you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

To arrange tabs on the side of the control, set the `Alignment` property of the `TabControl` to `Left` or `Right`.